# How to create a Child process depending on it's Parent?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

My application (**main.exe**) is executing a Child process (**child.exe**) using `ShellExecuteEx`.

But when I close or kill (via Process-Explorer) **main.exe** the child process remains active.

How to gracefully handle that, when **main.exe** terminates **child.exe** terminates also?

Comment: Get the main executable to send a message to the child executable when the main executable closes.

Comment: not when then main executable gets killed

Comment: Jobs appears to be a graceful solution. Also, you can inherit parent process handle and wait for it be be signaled upon termination.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use [jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Main executable should [create a job object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then you'll need to [set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE flag to your job object.

```
uses
  JobsApi;
//...
var
  jLimit: TJobObjectExtendedLimitInformation;

  hJob := CreateJobObject(nil, PChar('JobName');
  if hJob <> 0 then
  begin
    jLimit.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags := JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
      SetInformationJobObject(hJob, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, @jLimit,
        SizeOf(TJobObjectExtendedLimitInformation));
  end;
```

Then you need to execute another process with [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function where `dwCreationFlags` must be set to `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB`. If this function succeeds call `AssignProcessToJobObject`.

```
function ExecuteProcess(const EXE : String; const AParams: string = ''; AJob: Boolean = True): THandle;
var
  SI : TStartupInfo;
  PI : TProcessInformation;
  AFlag: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  FillChar(SI,SizeOf(SI),0);
  SI.cb := SizeOf(SI);

  if AJob then
    AFlag := CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB
  else
    AFlag := 0;


  if CreateProcess(
     nil,
     PChar(EXE + ' ' + AParams),
     nil,
     nil,
     False,
     AFlag,
     nil,
     nil,
     SI,
     PI
     ) then
  begin
   { close thread handle }
    CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
    Result := PI.hProcess;
  end;
end;
//...
  hApp := ExecuteProcess('PathToExecutable');

  if hApp <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
     AssignProcessToJobObject(hJob, hApp);
  end;
```

When all of this done all the child processes will be automatically terminated even if the main executable has been killed. You can get the JobsApi unit [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30851192/JobsApi.pas). Note: I've not tested it with Delphi 7.

EDIT: [Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30851192/Jobs.zip) you can download working demo project.

Comment: I have tested your code. I used the `CreateJobObject` on my Form create. added a Button for `ExecuteProcess`. the child process runs ok, `AssignProcessToJobObject` returns True. but when I close my parent application the child process remains alive.

Comment: @zigi70 Probably you are doing something wrong. We are using this technique successfully in our multi-modular software. I've edited my answer and included my working demo project source code link.

Comment: I have uploaded my project [here](http://www.4shared.com/zip/1yveHVAO/Jobs.html). would you be so kind to take a look.

Comment: Tested your project with D7/Delphi 2009. running on XP SP3. same result... notepad.exe remains. (at first I thought it was the full path issue which I did not provide in my application)

Comment: @zigi70 I'm compiling it with Delphi XE and it works OK on both XP and Windows 7. As I've said I've not tested it with different Delphi versions but I cannot imagine why it doesn't work in your scenario.

Comment: @zigi70 I've downloaded your project and when I close the main application child process terminates (same if I kill the main process). What else are you expecting to see?

Comment: you wont believe if I tell you what causing this: [Process Explorer](http://forum.sysinternals.com/bug-job-Object-limit-kill-On-jobclose_topic4094.html) . is the one to blame! :-P

Comment: @Linas Links don't work any more. Please put them up again or add them here.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`Job Objects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161%28VS.85%29.aspx) , check these functions [`CreateJobObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682409%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`AssignProcessToJobObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681949%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

> A job object allows groups of processes to be managed as a unit. Job
>   objects are namable, securable, shareable objects that control
>   attributes of the processes associated with them. Operations performed
>   on a job object affect all processes associated with the job object.
>   Examples include enforcing limits such as working set size and process
>   priority or **terminating all processes associated with a job**.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's very cool code. It's working for me, but I add some changes to be able user to set show window flags for child processes like SW_SHOW/SW_HIDE.

...

```
function ExecuteProcess(const EXE : String; const AParams: string = '';
  const nCmdShow: Integer = SW_SHOW; AJob: Boolean = True): THandle;
var
  SI : TStartupInfo;
  PI : TProcessInformation;
  AFlag: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  FillChar(SI,SizeOf(SI),0);
  SI.cb := SizeOf(SI);
  SI.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  SI.wShowWindow := nCmdShow;

  if AJob then
    AFlag := CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB
  else
    AFlag := 0;
```

...